# Diameter of general linear group wrt monomials and fixed root subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra

Let $G=GL_n(F)$ where $F$ is a field.

Let $S\subset G$ be the collection of monomial matrices in $G$ union a fixed root subgroup $U_{\alpha}$ of $G$. I.e.
$$
U_{\alpha}:=\{I_n+\lambda E_{i,j} : \lambda \in F\},
$$

for some fixed choice of $i\neq j$.

Now it is well known that $\langle S \rangle =G$. My question is what is the diameter of the Cayley graph with respect to this generating set? I.e. if
$$
l(g):= \text{min}\{k|g=s_1\cdots s_k, s_i \in S\},
$$

then what is $d(G)=\text{max}_{g \in G} l(g)$?

Some initial observations:

by the Bruhat decomposition, for any $g$ we can write $g = b_1 \sigma b_2$ where $b_i$ are upper triangular and $\sigma$ is monomial. So $d(G) \leq 2d(B)+1$ ($d(B)$ defined in the obvious way).

So given $b\in G$ that is upper triangular, what is $l(b)$? Well we can conjugate the root subgroup $U_{\alpha}$ by a permutation matrix and this moves our non-zero off diagonal entry around for a cost of 3 generators. Now if all upper off diagonal entries of $b$ are non-zero the total cost is going to be something like $(3/2)(n^2-n)$. Maybe adding a final diagonal matrix for any necessary rescaling, it looks like $l(b)\leq (3/2)(n^2-n)+1$.
We conclude that
$$
l(G)\leq 3(n^2-n)+3.
$$

The above calculation is a bit rough, mainly because I expect that we can do far better. For problems like this it often seems that $l(G)$ is "almost best possible", that is the smallest $k$ such that $\vert S \vert^k=\vert G \vert$ maybe $+1$ or $+2$.

On this line of thinking, assuming that $\vert F \vert =q$ we have something like
$\vert S \vert \sim n!q^{n+1}$ and $\vert G \vert \sim q^{n^2-n}$ so we might hope for a bound on $d(G)$ that is linear in $n$ (even better if $q<<n$.

Any ideas or references appreciated, thanks.